# Vue 3 equivalent of beforeMount in createApp

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

How can I call `beforeMount` from `createApp` in Vue 3? This worked in Vue 2.x:

```
const app = new Vue({
  store,
  el: '#app',
  beforeMount () {
    localStorage.setItem('something', something)
  },
  template: `<App></App>`
})
```

I can't find the Vue 3 syntax, this doesn't work.

```
const app = createApp(App)
app.use(store)
app.mount('#app')
app.beforeMount() {
  console.log('test')
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can pass an object of methods that you would export in a regular single-file vue component within `createApp`:

```js
const app = createApp({
  setup() {
    console.log("take it back now ya'll");
  }
})
```

[Documentation](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/instance-methods.html#instance-methods) - See First Example